# How to implement a few user's geoposition using yandex_kit map?

Tags: android, flutter

Hey guys :) maybe I didn't notice but I have a question:

how can I display a few user's `geoposition` (about 10 people, I supposed) using [yandex_mapkit](https://pub.dev/packages/yandex_mapkit)  for flutter?

I read a lot in the documentation but it does not have an answer. I just switched to the development of mobile apps for android and do not quite understand how to implement it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1- install**

[Installation](https://pub.dev/packages/yandex_mapkit)

**2- Check out API reference**

[API docs](https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.html/)

3- Implement from javascript code

[Examples](https://yandex.com/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark/)